# Javascript behaving inconsistently with PHP include files

Tags: php, javascript

I have a very simple javascript animation that looks like this

```
$(function() {
$('#slider1').cycle();
$('#slider2').cycle();
});
```

Im then calling in this script like this into my head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/slider.js"></script>
```

Then the divs that have the id "slider1" and "slider2" are contained in php include files being called into the page like this:

```
<?php include('assets/col1.php'); ?>
```

The code in the include file looks like this:

```
<div id="slider1">
<img src="images/image1.png" />
<img src="images/imgae2.png" />
<img src="images/image3.png" />
<img src="images/image4.png" />
</div>
```

Which works fine except when you get to IE8 or IE9. The javascript will work about 75% of the time which is why this has me baffled. When you load the page or come back to the page, every once in awhile it just doesn't activate the javascript and all the images render in one long column (essentially what it looks like with no js function)

I suspect its something in the order in which IE9 is loading the PHP and the javascript but I am only a novice in both js and php so some very clear help on how to fix this would be really great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Opps forgot to mention I am using cycle-light.js plugin from http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/lite/

Comment: PHP includes the files on the server, and then sends the results to the user (client). So browsers does not do anything with the PHP part of your code. But try using the debugger, think it is `F12` to open it, and check if there is any errors.

Answer (score 1):

Soooo long story long...

PHP will return interpreted HTML. Every time you include a file, PHP will flush the buffers, which means, certain content is returned to the browser prior to others. While this happens, the page is still in a loading state.

For this reason, you need to make sure you call `$(document).ready(function(e){  ...  });`. This will give you code a chance to finish flushing the buffers and load into the browser, before the javascript is executed..

Comment: Trying it now! I knew it was something simple because I couldn't find a straight answer anywhere!

Comment: Isn't `$(function(){...})` just a shorthand for that?

Comment: `$(function() {...})` is an alias for `$(document).ready(..)` http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: OK, well it seems to be working, (after I dumped the cache) however now all the images are visible for a second and then snap into place and the animation begins. It seems that while waiting for the page to load, the divs are just sitting there visible until its done. :-\

Comment: You could put them in a parent div and use `display: none` on it. This will hide them by default

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered a similar issue while using Dojo, which I solved as follows:
Set the main or the parent div display style as none:

```
<div id="g_body" style="display:none">
```

Now once Dojo finishes loading, I change the display style to block using the dojo.ready function:

```
require(["dojo/ready", "dojo/parser", "dijit/registry"], function(ready, parser, registry){
  ready(function(){
    if(document.getElementById("g_body")!= null){
        document.getElementById("g_body").setAttribute("style","display:block");
    }
  });
});
```

The pages then only shows when Dojo elements are completely loaded.

I believe there is something similar in jQuery, but I am not sure. Probably:

```
$(document).ready(function() {});
```

Hope this helps.